# Centre roman numbers in enumerate environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, enumerate, enumitem, roman-numerals

I have an enumerated list that uses roman numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*]
\item first entry
\item second entry
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately the 'i' and the 'ii' are now left-aligned. Is it possible to centre the enumerating column?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. The normal `enumerate` environment doesn't take an optional argument.

Comment: Yes, I forgot. I'm using the enumitem package; added it to the example.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[The `enumitem` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem) comes with a `left` and `right` alignment built in. The currently released version, `(v3.0)` allows you to define a custom alignment via `SetLabelAlign`:

[image]

Here are two versions, one without the `()` and another with the `()`.  Since you desired to have the parenthesis aligned as well, `\makebox[1.0em]` is used to ensure that the label is centered in a box of the specified width, so that the parenthesis will be just outside of this box and hence be aligned.  If your list is very long, you might need to increase the size via using `\makebox[1.5em]` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\SetLabelAlign{Center}{\hfil#1\hfil}
\SetLabelAlign{CenterWithParen}{\hfil(\makebox[1.0em]{#1})\hfil}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*,align=Center]
\item first entry
\item second entry
\item third entry
\end{enumerate}

\hrule

\begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*,align=CenterWithParen]
\item first entry
\item second entry
\item third entry
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For this you need at least version `3.0` of [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem).

Comment: @Werner: Thanks for pointing that out. I did not think of mentioning that as it is part of the current released code as part of TeXLive2011.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the solution. As a follow-up on this: Suppose I use `\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*),align=Center]`, is it possible to make the parenthesis equally wide? '(i)', and '(iii)' on top of one another do not look very nice...

Comment: @user7091: If I understand correctly what you want, you can use something like `\SetLabelAlign{Center}{(\makebox[1em]{\hfil#1\hfil})}` and then `\begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*,align=Center]\item...\end{enumerate}`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Thanks. I updated the solution. but modified the parameter of the `\makebox` slightly as that made more sense to me. Please correct me if I am mistaken.

Comment: @PeterGrill: your version will work fine.