# Center Aligning Labels in a enumerate environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumerate, enumitem

I am trying to get enumerate environment do the following:

```
     (subgroup)   some description of a subgroup of a group G.
      (hello!)    This subgroup is a hello subgroup of G and satisfies an
                  awkward  condition that it does not occur often!
    (long enough) It also satisfies long enough condition so that it is not trivial!
```

Based on the answer of Peter Grill and the ensuing discussion [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33145/10679), I came up with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\SetLabelAlign{Center}{\makebox[1em]{(#1)}}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[align=Center]
\item[subgroup] Some description of a subgroup of a group $G$.
\item[hello!] This subgroup is a hello subgroup of G and satisfies an awkward  condition that it does not occur often!
\item[long enough] It also satisfies long enough condition so that it is not trivial!
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

This leaves me with:

[image: mwe.png]

I'd be glad if somebody can help me fix this code!

**Edit** Playing around a little bit, I figure that increasing the `\makebox` width(?), I could get it to write things without overlapping. But, this breaks alignment. Could someone please explain this?

Comment: Not sure this is what you're looking for, but increasing the width of your box to, say, `6em` stops the overlapping.

Comment: @Jonathan Yes, I just figured that out and even edited to add it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use a description list here instead of misusing `itemize`.  In order for this to work you need to specify the longest label you will have.  You need to have `enumitem` calculate the left margin for you, using `leftmargin=!`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\mylongest}
\setlength{\mylongest}{\widthof{The longest label I will need}}
\addtolength{\mylongest}{\labelsep}
\SetLabelAlign{CenterWithParen}{\makebox[\mylongest]{(#1)}}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}[style=unboxed,align=CenterWithParen,labelwidth=\mylongest,leftmargin=!]
\item[Foo]{This is a foo item}
\item[FooBar]{This is a foobar item}
\item[A longer description]{A longer label}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: One can use `environ` and `\NewEnviron` in order to avoid guessing the widest label. There's no need to load `calc`, because `\settowidth{\mylongest}{<text>}` is defined in the kernel.

Answer (score 8):

One can use `environ` and so avoid guessing at the widest label.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{environ}
\newlength{\cdescwidth}
\SetLabelAlign{CenterWithParen}{\makebox[\cdescwidth]{\normalfont(#1)}}

\NewEnviron{cdesc}{%
  \setbox0=\vbox{% measure the label widths
    \global\cdescwidth=0pt
    \def\item[##1]{%
      \settowidth{\dimen0}{(##1)}%
      \ifdim\dimen0>\cdescwidth
        \global\cdescwidth=\dimen0
      \fi}
    \BODY}
  % set the label width
  \global\advance\cdescwidth\labelsep
  \begin{description}[
    font=\normalfont,
    style=unboxed,
    align=CenterWithParen,
    labelwidth=\cdescwidth,
    leftmargin=!
  ]
  % typeset the contents
  \BODY
  \end{description}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{cdesc}
\item[Foo] This is a foo item
\item[FooBar] This is a foobar item
\item[A longer description] A longer label
\end{cdesc}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A different implementation with `expl3` that avoids the tentative typesetting of the whole lot.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\SetLabelAlign{CenterWithParen}{\makebox[\l__kan_cdesc_dim]{\normalfont(#1)}}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{cdesc}{+b}
 {
  \__kan_cdesc_setup:n { #1 }
  \begin{description}[
    font=\normalfont,
    style=unboxed,
    align=CenterWithParen,
    labelwidth=\l__kan_cdesc_dim,
    leftmargin=!
  ]
  % typeset the contents
  #1
  \end{description}
 }{}

\dim_new:N \l__kan_cdesc_dim

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__kan_cdesc_setup:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__kan_cdesc_seq { \item } { [] #1 }
  \dim_zero:N \l__kan_cdesc_dim
  \seq_map_function:NN \l__kan_cdesc_seq \__kan_cdesc_measure:n
  \dim_add:Nn \l__kan_cdesc_dim { \labelsep }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__kan_cdesc_measure:n
 {
  \__kan_cdesc_measure_aux:w #1 \q_stop
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__kan_cdesc_measure_aux:w [#1] #2 \q_stop
 {
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box {\normalfont(#1)}
  \dim_set:Nn \l__kan_cdesc_dim
   {
    \dim_max:nn { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box } { \l__kan_cdesc_dim }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\begin{cdesc}
\item[Foo] This is a foo item
\item[FooBar] This is a foobar item
\item[A longer description] A longer label
\end{cdesc}
\end{document}
```