# Center labels in enumerate within a theorem

Tags: theorems, enumerate, enumitem, amsthm

Here is a minimal working example, based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33144/centre-roman-numbers-in-enumerate-environment):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\SetLabelAlign{Center}{\hfil#1\hfil}

\newtheoremstyle{theorem}{1em}{}{\itshape}{}{\bfseries}{}{1em}
{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (\normalfont\textit{#3})}}
\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
\mbox{}\vspace{-0.175cm}
\begin{enumerate}[align=Center,font=\normalfont,label=(\roman*)]
\item First proposition.
\item Second proposition.
\item Third proposition.
\end{enumerate}
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

The labels should be centered, and the items (in this case, the propositions) should be aligned to the left.

EDIT: It should look something like this (see link):

```
  (i)    1st item
 (iii)   3rd item
  (x)    10th item
(xviii)  18th item
 (xxi)   21st item
```

That is, the column of labels should be to the left of the column of items, and the labels should be centered in this column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The label separation should be zero, and the label width should be the same as the left margin. I also added `topsep=0pt` so you don't need to guess its value.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\SetLabelAlign{Center}{\hfil#1\hfil}

\newtheoremstyle{theorem}{1em}{}{\itshape}{}{\bfseries}{}{1em}
{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (\normalfont\textit{#3})}}
\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{thm}
\mbox{}
\begin{enumerate}[
  align=Center,
  font=\normalfont,
  label=(\roman*),
  topsep=0pt,
  labelsep=0pt,
  labelwidth=!            
]
\item First proposition.
\item Second proposition.
\item Third proposition.
\end{enumerate}
\end{thm}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you plan to have 18 items, increase `leftmargin`. Do I consider this nice? No way.

Comment: Nice solution, thanks. I don't have anywhere near 18 items, I just used it for illustration since xviii has an odd number of characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsthm,showframe}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\SetLabelAlign{Center}{\strut{\parbox[t]{\labelwidth}
                            {\centering#1}}%
                            }

\newtheoremstyle{theorem}{1em}{}{\itshape}{}{\bfseries}{}{1em}
{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (\normalfont\textit{#3})}}
\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
\mbox{}\vspace{-0.175cm}
\begin{enumerate}[align=Center,font=\normalfont,label=(\roman*),leftmargin=*,]
\item First proposition.
\item Second proposition.
\item Third proposition.
\end{enumerate}
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]